# d3.js: Group Chords in a Diagram via a Single Colour

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

My aim is to group chords via a single colour similar to this (here it's red, grey, blue):
[image]

I thought about something like this:

```
var groups = [
        {sIndex: 0, eIndex: 1, title: 'Group1', color: '#004F9F'},
        {sIndex: 2, eIndex: 5, title: 'Group2', color: '#df7c00'},
        {sIndex: 6, eIndex: 7, title: 'Group3', color: '#0D57A6'},
        {sIndex: 8, eIndex: 9, title: 'Group4', color: '#008A34'}
    ];
```

The `sIndex` & `eIndex` define the start and end of each group. However, I don't know how to loop it properly.

Here's my whole code:

```js
d3.csv("description.csv", function(d) {
 return d;
}, draw);

function draw(description) {

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //////////////////////// Set-Up ////////////////////////////
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 var margin = {left:90, top:90, right:90, bottom:90},
   width = Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000) - margin.left - margin.right,
     height = Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000) - margin.top - margin.bottom,
     innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * .39,
     outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.1;

 var names = [ "Site1", "Site2",
        "YouTube","Twitter", "Google+", "Instagram",
        "App1", "App2",
        "Content1", "Content2" ],
      colors = ["#301E1E", "#083E77", "#342350", "#567235", "#8B161C", "#DF7C00"],
      opacityDefault = 0.8;

   var matrix = [
       [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
       [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
       [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
       [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1],
       [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],
       [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
       [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],
       [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]
     ];

 //define grouping with colors
 var groups = [
  {sIndex: 0, eIndex: 1, title: 'Group1', color: '#004F9F'},
  {sIndex: 2, eIndex: 5, title: 'Group2', color: '#df7c00'},
  {sIndex: 6, eIndex: 7, title: 'Group3', color: '#0D57A6'},
  {sIndex: 8, eIndex: 9, title: 'Group4', color: '#008A34'}
 ];

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /////////// Create scale and layout functions //////////////
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
     .domain(d3.range(names.length))
   .range(colors);

 var chord = d3.chord()
     .padAngle(.15)
     .sortChords(d3.descending);

 var arc = d3.arc()
     .innerRadius(innerRadius*1.01)
     .outerRadius(outerRadius);

 var path = d3.ribbon()
   .radius(innerRadius);


 var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2 + margin.left) + "," + (height/2 + margin.top) + ")")
   .datum(chord(matrix));

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ////////////////// Draw outer Arcs /////////////////////////
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 var outerArcs = svg.selectAll("g.group")
  .data(function(chu) { return chu.groups; })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "group")
  .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
  .on("mouseout", fade(opacityDefault))

 outerArcs.append("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) {return colors(d.index); })
  .attr("d", arc);

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ////////////////////// Append names ////////////////////////
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 //Append the label names on the outside
 outerArcs.append("text")
   .each(function(d) { d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2; })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("class", "titles")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null; })
   .attr("transform", function(d) {
   return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")"
   + "translate(" + (outerRadius + 10) + ")"
   + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
   })
   .text(function(d,i) { return names[i]; });

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ////////////////// Draw inner chords ///////////////////////
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 svg.selectAll("path.chord")
  .data(function(chords) { return chords; })
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "chord")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.source.index); })
  .style("opacity", opacityDefault)
  .attr("d", path);

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 ////////////////// Extra Functions /////////////////////////
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 //Returns an event handler for fading a given chord group.
 function fade(opacity) {
   return function(d,i) {
     svg.selectAll("path.chord")
         .filter(function(d) { return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i; })
   .transition()
         .style("opacity", opacity);
   };
 }//fade
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Testing</title>

  <!-- D3.js & tool-tip -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <style>
   body {
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
     fill: #2B2B2B;
     cursor: default;
   }

   @media (min-width: 600px) {
    #chart{
     font-size: 14px;
    }
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id = "chart"></div>
  <script src = "script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the `groups` array to get the colour:

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
    var thisGroup = groups.filter(function(e) {
        return e.sIndex === d.index || e.eIndex === d.index;
    });
    return thisGroup[0] ? thisGroup[0].color : "gray";
})
```

Here is your code with it:

```js
draw();

function draw(description) {

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////////// Set-Up ////////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var margin = {
      left: 90,
      top: 90,
      right: 90,
      bottom: 90
    },
    width = Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000) - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000) - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * .39,
    outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.1;

  var names = ["Site1", "Site2",
      "YouTube", "Twitter", "Google+", "Instagram",
      "App1", "App2",
      "Content1", "Content2"
    ],
    colors = ["#301E1E", "#083E77", "#342350", "#567235", "#8B161C", "#DF7C00"],
    opacityDefault = 0.8;

  var matrix = [
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
  ];

  //define grouping with colors
  var groups = [{
    sIndex: 0,
    eIndex: 1,
    title: 'Group1',
    color: '#004F9F'
  }, {
    sIndex: 2,
    eIndex: 5,
    title: 'Group2',
    color: '#df7c00'
  }, {
    sIndex: 6,
    eIndex: 7,
    title: 'Group3',
    color: '#0D57A6'
  }, {
    sIndex: 8,
    eIndex: 9,
    title: 'Group4',
    color: '#008A34'
  }];

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////// Create scale and layout functions //////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(d3.range(names.length))
    .range(colors);

  var chord = d3.chord()
    .padAngle(.15)
    .sortChords(d3.descending);

  var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius * 1.01)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

  var path = d3.ribbon()
    .radius(innerRadius);


  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + margin.left) + "," + (height / 2 + margin.top) + ")")
    .datum(chord(matrix));

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////// Draw outer Arcs /////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var outerArcs = svg.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(function(chu) {
      return chu.groups;
    })
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group")
    .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
    .on("mouseout", fade(opacityDefault))

  outerArcs.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      var thisGroup = groups.filter(function(e) {
        return e.sIndex === d.index || e.eIndex === d.index;
      });
      return thisGroup[0] ? thisGroup[0].color : "gray";
    })
    .attr("d", arc);

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////////// Append names ////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Append the label names on the outside
  outerArcs.append("text")
    .each(function(d) {
      d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("class", "titles")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.angle > Math.PI ? "end" : null;
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")" + "translate(" + (outerRadius + 10) + ")" + (d.angle > Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : "");
    })
    .text(function(d, i) {
      return names[i];
    });

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////// Draw inner chords ///////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  svg.selectAll("path.chord")
    .data(function(chords) {
      return chords;
    })
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "chord")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      var thisGroup = groups.filter(function(e) {
        return e.sIndex == d.source.index || e.eIndex == d.source.index;
      });
      return thisGroup[0] ? thisGroup[0].color : "gray";
    })
    .style("opacity", opacityDefault)
    .attr("d", path);

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////// Extra Functions /////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Returns an event handler for fading a given chord group.
  function fade(opacity) {
    return function(d, i) {
      svg.selectAll("path.chord")
        .filter(function(d) {
          return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i;
        })
        .transition()
        .style("opacity", opacity);
    };
  } //fade
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Testing</title>

  <!-- D3.js & tool-tip -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <style>
   body {
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
     fill: #2B2B2B;
     cursor: default;
   }

   @media (min-width: 600px) {
    #chart{
     font-size: 14px;
    }
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id = "chart"></div>
  <script src = "script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

PS: You have some problem with those indices, that's why I wrote a ternary function to return "gray" if the filtered value is `undefined`.